# Tensorflow Object Detection API: I am not sure if It is running correctly

Tags: tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am making a object detection model by official Tensorflow Object Detection API 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

But the problem is that I don't know if it proceeds.
It literally got stuck in the certain status.

Here is the status.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSdMG.png)

I waited for finishing it over 24 hours but it didn't.

Any advice for me?

MODEL: ssd_efficientdet_d1_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.config 
DATA: COCO style Custom data which contains 2,000 Images. 
(There are about 50~100 boxes per image.)

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please add code how you start execution and edit your log as text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.